# Does Apache NiFi support batch processing?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to know if Apache NiFi supports running processors until completion.

**"the execution of a series of processors in process group wait for anothor process group results execution to be complete".**

**For example:**

Suppose there are three processors in NiFi UI.

```
    P1-->P2-->P3
    P-->Processor
```

Now I need to run P1 if it run completely then run P2 And finally it will run like sequence but one wait for another to be complete.

**EDIT-1:**

Just for example I have data in web URL. I can download that data using `GetHTTP` Processor. Now I stored that in `putFile` content. If file saved in `putFile` directory then run `FetchFile` to process that file into my database like below workflow.

```
GetHTTP-->PutFile-->FetchFile-->DB
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

NiFi itself is not really a batch processing system, it is a data flow system more geared towards continuous processing. Having said that, there are some techniques you can use to do batch-like operations, depending on which processors you're using.

The Split processors (SplitText, SplitJSON, etc.) write attributes to the flow files that include a "fragment.identifier" which is unique for all splits created from an incoming flow file, and "fragment.count" which is the total number of those splits. Processors like MergeContent use those attributes to process a whole batch (aka fragment), so the output from those kinds of processors would occur after an entire batch/fragment has been processed.

Another technique is to write an empty file in a temp directory when the job is complete, then a ListFile processor (pointing at that temp directory) would issue a flow file when the file is detected.

Can you describe more about the processors in your flow, and how you would know when a batch was complete?

Comment: Since the original answer, NiFi has added record-based processors which allow you to perform operations on multiple "records" in a FlowFile. Records could be each line in a CSV file, each object in a top-level JSON or XML array, etc. This is another kind of batching technique as you can perform the same operation on a number of records in a single flowfile, thereby avoiding the need to split -> transform -> merge