# Using NiFi for scheduling Hadoop batch processes

Tags: hadoop, batch-processing, oozie, apache-nifi

According to [NiFi's homepage](https://nifi.apache.org/), it "supports powerful and scalable directed graphs of data routing, transformation, and system mediation logic".

I've been playing with NiFi in the last couple of months and can't help wondering why not using it also for scheduling batch processes.

Let's say I have a **use case** in which data flows into Hadoop, processed by a series of Hive \ MapReduce jobs, then exported to some external NoSql database to be used by some system.

Using NiFi in order to ingest and flow data into Hadoop is a use case that NiFi was built for.
However, using Nifi in order to schedule the jobs on Hadoop ("Oozie-like") is a use case I haven't encountered others implementing, and since it seems completely possible to implement, I'm trying to understand if there are reasons not to do so.

The gains of doing it all on NiFi is that one will get a visual representation of the entire course of data, from source to destination in one place. In case of complicated flows it is very important for maintenance.

In other words - my question is: **Are there reasons not to use NiFi as a scheduler\coordinator for batch processes**? If so - what problems may arise in such a use case?

---

PS - I've read this: "[Is Nifi having batch processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607235/is-nifi-having-batch-processing)" - but my question aims to a different sense of "batch processing in NiFi" than the one raised in the attached question

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you would have a concise visual representation of all steps in the process were the schedule triggers present on the flow canvas, but NiFi was not designed as a scheduler/coordinator. [Here is a comparison of some scheduler options](http://bytepawn.com/luigi-airflow-pinball.html).

Using NiFi to control scheduling feels like a "hammer" solution in search of a problem. It will reduce the ease of defining those schedules programmatically or interacting with them from external tools. Theoretically, you could define the schedule format, read them into NiFi from a file, datasource, endpoint, etc., and use `ExecuteStreamCommand`, `ExecuteScript`, or `InvokeHTTP` processors to kick off the batch process. This feels like introducing an unnecessary intermediate step however. If consolidation & visualization is what you are going for, you could have a monitoring flow segment ingest those schedule definitions from their native format (Oozie, XML, etc.) and display them in NiFi without making NiFi responsible for defining and executing the scheduling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to clarify my question: I'm aware of NiFi's advantages (and the fact that data should be flowed through NiFi in order to gain them), and intend to use them when relevant. However, in many use cases I want to run batch processes and wonder what will I miss \ where will I fail if I'll do so.