# Batch processing flowfiles in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have written custom nifi processor which tries to batch process input flow files.

However, it seems it is not behaving as expected. Here is what happening:

> I copy paste some files on server. `FethFromServerProcessor` fetches those files from server and puts it in `queue1`. `MyCustomProcessor` reads files in batch from `queue1`. I have `batchSize` property defined on `MyCustomProcessor` and inside its `onTrigger()` method, I am getting all flow files from `queue1` in current batch by doing following:
>
> ```
> session.get(context.getProperty(batchSize).asInteger())
> ```
>
> First line of `onTrigger()` creates timestamp and adds this timestamp on all flow files. So all files in the batch should have same timestamp. However, that is not happening. Usually first flow file get one timestamp and rest of the flow files get other timestamp.

It seems that when `FetchFromServerProcessor` fetches first file from server and puts it in the `queue1`, `MyCustomProcessor` gets triggered and it fetches all files from queue. Incidentally, it happens that there used to be single file, which is picked up as only file in this batch. By the time `MyCustomProcessor` has processed this file, `FetchFromServerProcessor` has fetched all the files from server and put them in the `queue1`. So after processing first file, `MyCustomProcessor` takes all the files in `queue1` and forms second batch, whereas I want all files picked up in single batch.

How can I avoid two batches getting formed? I see that people discuss wait-notify in this context:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607235/is-nifi-having-batch-processing), [2](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/). But I am not able to make quick sense out of these posts. Can someone give me minimal steps to achieve this using wait notify processors or can someone point me to minimal tutorial which gives step by step procedure to use wait-notify processors? Also is wait-notify pattern standard approach to solve batch related problem I explained? Or is there any other standard approach to get this done?

Comment: could you describe a logic to determine that queue is incomplete? because it could be absolutely different. from your words sounds like you just need to add some delay and rollback in case if you got too "young" file with `session.get(n)`

Comment: and what is it `FetchFromServerProcessor` ?

Comment: `FetchFromServerProcessor` could be anything which fetches files from remote server, say SFTP server or Amazon S3, so it takes time to fetch files one by one and put them in `queue1`.

Comment: I have currently no logic to determine if queue is incomplete. Question is what logic it should be? I cannot rely on some delay, right? (as I cant be sure how much exact time will it take to fetch all files in current batch over the network). I can have count of files put on server as attribute of flow files, but how can I use it?

Comment: it seems you need to change logic of FetchFromServerProcessor... because only this processor knows when it ends...

Comment: well I didnt mention that I have one processor (say `ProcessorX`) which feeds `FetchFromServerProcessor` which files to fetch, so `ProcessorX` does know which files to process next in the batch. I can make it to count those files and set the count as attribute of flow file. But, how can I make `MyCustomProcessor` to make use of this count? How can make it wait till n number of files are present in `queue1`, before polling that queue and form the batch?

Comment: see how MergeContent works when waits for a number of files. if your nifi is not distributed then the simplest way to call `session.rollback()` if `session.get(n)` does not return all the files.

Comment: **(1)** So you mean to say inside `MyCustomProcessor.onTrigger()`, I should check whether `session.get(context.getProperty(batchSize).asInteger()).size() == inputFilesCount`, & if above condition is false, do session.rollback()?  **(2)** If yes, then where should I set the value of `inputFilesCount`? I can get count of files pasted on server. Should I set it on flow file using `UpdateAttribute` processor? & then do: `List<FlowFile> flowFiles = session.get(context.getProperty(batchSize).asInteger()); if(flowfiles.size() == flowfiles.get(0).getAttribute("inputFilesCount")) session.rollback();`?

Comment: [continued from last comment] **(3)** Wont it make `MyCustomProcessor` to start and rollback session for each input flow file until all files are received? **(4)** Also is it ok to set flow file attribute using `UpdateAttribute` as explained in (2) since that will set same value for attribute on all files? It just feels weird, as it will require me to do `flowfiles.get(0)` (as explained in (2)).

Comment: to all your questions - yes, i mean this. why do you need such batch processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if this batch size is the required count of incoming flowfiles to `CustomProcessor`, so why not write your `CustomProcessor#onTrigger()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
    final ComponentLog logger = getLogger();
    // Try to get n flowfiles from incoming queue
    final Integer desiredFlowfileCount = context.getProperty(batchSize).asInteger();
    final int queuedFlowfileCount = session.getQueueSize().getObjectCount();
    if (queuedFlowfileCount < desiredFlowfileCount) {
        // There are not yet n flowfiles queued up, so don't try to run again immediately
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Only {} flowfiles queued; waiting for {}", new Object[]{queuedFlowfileCount, desiredFlowfileCount});
        }
        context.yield();
        return;
    }

    // If we're here, we do have at least n queued flowfiles
    List<FlowFile> flowfiles = session.get(desiredFlowfileCount);

    try {
        // TODO: Perform work on all flowfiles
        flowfiles = flowfiles.stream().map(f -> session.putAttribute(f, "timestamp", "my static timestamp value")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        session.transfer(flowfiles, REL_SUCCESS);

        // If extending AbstractProcessor, this is handled for you and you don't have to explicitly commit
        session.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Helpful error message");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.error("Further stacktrace: ", e);
        }
        // Penalize the flowfiles if appropriate (also done for you if extending AbstractProcessor and an exception is thrown from this method
        session.rollback(true);
        //  --- OR ---
        // Transfer to failure if they can't be retried
        session.transfer(flowfiles, REL_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The Java 8 `stream` syntax can be replaced by this if it's unfamiliar:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < flowfiles.size(); i++) {
            // Write the same timestamp value onto all flowfiles
            FlowFile f = flowfiles.get(i);
            flowfiles.set(i, session.putAttribute(f, "timestamp", "my timestamp value"));
        }
```

The [semantics between penalization](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#penalization-vs-yielding) (telling the processor to delay performing work on a specific flowfile) and yielding (telling the processor to wait some period of time to try performing any work again) are important.

You probably also want the [`@TriggerSerially` annotation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#performing-the-work) on your custom processor to ensure you do not have multiple threads running such that a race condition could arise.

Comment: How courteous to re-expand the Java 8 stuff in your answer, Andy.