# Nifi: Merging multiple XML files into one big xml through MergeContent Processor

Tags: xml, merge, batch-processing, apache-nifi

I have a question regarding batch processing of Nifi.

Since processing speed of Nifi (converting xml to csv) is slow now, I was asked to make it 6 times faster than now. And need to do batch processing on Nifi. I did some research and seemingly, the only way for batch processing is merging multiple flowfiles  into bigger one with MergeContent processor according to the following article.

[Is Nifi having batch processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607235/is-nifi-having-batch-processing)

I understand MergeContent processor is cpu-intensive processor and should be avoided if possible. In that sense, not quite sure if that improves the overall speed.

But are there any ways to merge multiple xml (30KB~3MB) into bigger one (~120 MB) and possible for python xml module to read merged xml? (I implemented ExecuteStreamCommand which runs external python script to modify the nested xml format into the flattened one so that Nifi controller service can convert xml to csv format)

Is batch processing on Nifi good way for performance optimization in the first place??

Comment: In my opinion, it is still small enough.

Comment: What would you think is the desirable xml size? 1 GB?? And won't it rather slow down the speed because of additional processor added (MergeContent and etc)

Comment: ihmo. mergecontent stops data processing to collect files into one bundle. so, in terms of speed you loose time. i suggest to optimize existing processors.

Comment: What processor are you using to convert CSV to XML? and also, how many lines are in each CSV, or maybe how large is each CSV in size?

Comment: @daggett Yes I know that mergecontent slows down the performance and Nifi in itself is not designed to do batch processing because it means it stops the flow after the processor which does batch operation like MergeContent. I did everything I could like assigning multiple concurrent task to bottleneck processors, change run schedule longer (higher throughput for quick processor like UpdateAttribute),applied load balance, and so on. But need to further improve the speed somehow.

Comment: @BryanBende Sorry for confusion. It is actually conversion from xml to csv. Each xml file ranges between a few KB to a few MB. And I am using Nifi native controller service to do the conversion. The size of CSV output has to be between 100 MB and 120 MB, so need to do merge multiple xml into bigger one for the output size.

Comment: @Micro_Andy, could you share xml sample with few rows, processor that you are using, and csv that corresponds to this xml.

Comment: @daggett I am sorry that I cannot share xml template and data here. But, new pipeline which does batch-like operation is as follows. ListHDFS->FetchHDFS->ControlRate->MergeContent (Combining multiple small xml (like a few KB~ a few MB) into bigger one 100MB~120MB) -> ExcuteStreamCommand (Extract necessary tag and elements as column and its value and output as csv format through sys.stdout.write), splitContent (Spliting csv by some type)->UpdateAttribute (Update filename)-> PutHDFS.